# How to hide Android titlebar when Google Play Games is initialising?

Tags: android, libgdx, google-play-games

When I initialise Google Play Games, when my game has loaded, and the "connecting to Google Play Games" window appears at the start - the Android titlebar also momentarily appears. It disappears once the GPG login window disappears. How do I stop that happening? In my game's manifest, I have the following style set within the activity tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

This obviously works, as I don't see the toolbar when my game is running. I had a look at the Google Play Game Services GameBaseUtils manifest, and it doesn't have any activity tags, so I added the NoTitleBar style to the application tags like this:

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
</application>
```

However, the title bar still shows (momentarily) when the game loads and Google Play Games is initialised. Is there any way to fully get rid of the titlebar when GPG initialises?

Answer (score -1):

Do this inside your `onCreate()` method.
Cheers!

```
//Remove title bar

this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

Comment: I added your code to the onCreate method in AndroidLauncher, but it doesn't work. SetContentView isn't used with libGDX projects.